# How to implement AyncStorage in React Native to Save API Data and then use it throughout the App?

Tags: react-native

I have implemented this code to store Response Data from API. But this is not working and there is no error also. Please help me

```
.then((response) => response.json())

.then((responseJson) => {
    //  console.log(responseJson);
    if (responseJson.res_status == "200") {
        //console.log(responseJson.res_data);       

        login = async () => {

            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(responseJson.res_data));
                console.log(responseJson.res_data);
                alert(responseJson.res_message);
                console.log(responseJson.res_data);
                Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successful');
            } catch (error) {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
                alert("Unsuccessful");
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the error? and how are you fetching the stored response that is key?

Comment: There is no error but Data is not stored in AsyncStorage. I am fetching res_data from API

Comment: Sir please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how ive implemented data in async storage, 
 1. Ive downloaded react native async storage library as in the below link form npm [rn-async-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/async-storage)

2.Next i have done same as you when storing the data in async storage like

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

await AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(responseJson.res_data));
```

3.Next now suppose in another page i want to fetch the details , i would do like

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Hope thats clear, feel free for doubts

Comment: Sir what is the problem in my code? Actually the controller is not going in '  login = async () => {
' this. Please help me

Comment: where are you calling login() like this? after that only it should be called, just call login() after function declaration and it should work i guess

Comment: login = () => {
  const { UserEmail, UserPassword } = this.state;
  let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (UserEmail == "") {
   alert("Please enter Email address");
  }
  else if (reg.test(UserEmail) === false) {
   alert("Email is not correct");
   return false;
  }
  else if (UserPassword == "") {
   alert("Please enter password");
  }

Comment: else {
   fetch('https://hashtaglabs.in/stctrain/api/user-access.php?api_key=1234&action=user_login', {
    method: 'post',
    header: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
     // we will pass our input data to server
     // email: userEmail,
     // password: userPassword

     login_access: UserEmail,
     login_pass: UserPassword,
     login_device: "863217033579489"
    })
   })

Comment: Sir this is the Code of Login. Here I fetch the JSON Data from API

Comment: can you post this in the question itself by editing it?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this and try.

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    if (responseJson.res_status == "200") {      

        login = async (responseJson.res_data) => {

            //Check data is available inside this function or not.                    
            //console.log("data",responseJson.res_data);

            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(responseJson.res_data));
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        }
```